# googletest with global static variable

Tags: c, googletest

let's imagine we have the following code snippet

```
// myfile.c
#include myfile.h

static int global_static_value;

bool check_it(int value) {
   if (global_static_value== value) {
    return true;
   } else {
    return false
   }
}

void set_value(int value) {
   global_static_value = value;
}

// myfile.h

bool check_it(int value)
void set_value(int value)
```

How to write google test for function `bool check_it(int value)` in order to test `true` and `false` return value?

PS: It is not allowed to `#include myfile.c` into google test

Comment: Just write a helper function, that allows you to change the value. Maybe the design is flawed if it needs global variables. You could make it with an `#ifdef google_test` if you don't want the function to be included in production code. What are the conditions that this value is set?

Comment: @Devolus it is not allowed to do that kind of changes.

Comment: OK. But then, you must have a condition on which the value is set, otherwise the value has no meaning, so you can force that condition in your intended direction. In my opinion one should not write tests for any arbitrary condition, but for use cases scenarios.

Comment: And you have this `set_value` function, anyway, so you can always call it in your testsetup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TEST_F(MyTestClass, MyTest)
{
    set_value(1);
    EXPECT_FALSE(check_it(2));
    EXPECT_TRUE(check_it(1));
}
```